# sharing one 110VAC circuit with two high amperage devices

Tags: switches, ac

I have a fairly simple need and there may be a commercially available device that does this, but I have not found it.

I need to buy/make a 110VAC device that will automatically switch between two devices plugged into it. It would have one plug and two (or more) receptacles. Receptacle "A" would be by default "on". Receptacle "B" would only turn on by demand by the device that is plugged into it switching on which would automatically switch off receptacle "A" before switching "B" on.

This is to prevent overloading a single circuit and tripping a breaker or over loading the wiring.

1. Is there a name for this type of device? I have searched Google without success.
2. Are there commercial sources for it already built?
3. Is there a way to build one otherwise?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! In order to get good answers you need to give us all of the relevant information. In this case, tell us as much as you can about your "A" and "B" devices. How exactly is "B" switched on?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't give much detail, so this is only a high level knee jerk reaction.

Get a relay appropriate for switching the two AC feeds.  Either make sure this is a break before make relay, or you can use two separate relays that you manage yourself.  The unenergized state routes the power to outlet A, with the energized state routing it to B.

That was the easy part.  The hard part is detecting which state the relay should be in.  One way or another you'll have to measure current on B to decide when to switch it off.  This is probably best done with a current transformer.  This can also be used to detect current draw on B when it is switched off.  Instead of switching off B completely, there is a resistor providing a little bleed current, like a few mA.  The relay for B shorts accross this resistor to turn on B.

When device on B tries to draw current, it will get just enough to detect via the current transformer.  The current transformer output is conditioned and presented to the A/D input of a micro, which then looks at the magnitude of current and decides what to do.  It can also do a few useful things you didn't mention, like wait a second or two to switch either direction so as to not respond to short glitches.  It can also easily manage two relays to perform break before make.

Answer (score 2):

As a student I lived for a short time in a caravan. I used a circuit like you described, but with more outlets, to switch the available current (10A at 220V) between the various heat-generating devices: cooking was highest priority, air heating next, a water-filled radiator lowest. (There might have been more.)

I simply detected the current by a few turns (20 or so) of the current-conducting wire round a reed switch. When energized, it cut of the power to 'lower priority' devices by activating a relay.

A problem was that the cooking gear could draw either half or full power, and the reed switch had to engage reliably at half power. I recall a lot of buzzing from this 'switchbox', but it worked reliably for the ~ 6 months I lived there.

Comment: This is exactly the scenario. Two AC devices about 15A each sharing one 20A circuit. It needs to auto switch. So would the reed switch react fast enough to prevent over loading of the circuit if both were on during the transition? They are both resistive loads. But wouldn't wrapping the reed with an AC load line cause the contact to chatter? Maybe that was the buzzing you spoke of?

Comment: In mys situation the switchover was apparently fast enough, YMMV. The reeds did chatter/buzz/hum, but at that time that was the level of electronics I was familiar with. Now I might have preferred a hall switch.

Answer (score 0):

For current sensing I'm thinking of a solution using a Hall-Effect-Based Linear Current Sensor such as [ACS712](http://www.allegromicro.com/Products/Current-Sensor-ICs/Zero-To-Fifty-Amp-Integrated-Conductor-Sensor-ICs/ACS712.aspx).
It can be directly connected to AC loads(supports up to 30 amps), has a very low resistance, the output is isolated from the input and most importantly the output is a DC voltage proportional to the input current so there is no need for any conversions of AC to DC.

The output selection mechanism can be based on a couple of comparators driving solid state relays or use a microcontroller to do more complex calculations if needed.